# (MOVED) ./configure W/ Cygwin on Windows Return's Cannot Determine OS

Tags: windows, build, cygwin, configuration-files

(THIS POST HAS BEEN MOVED)

I don't know if this is the 'best' place to put this, please correct me if I should move this somewere else (I won't be affended).

I installed CygWin, and following the tutorial here: https://www.wired.com/2010/02/compile_software_from_source_code/

(Yes, this is my first time Building from source)

And I got ALL the way to running ./configure, when I get a dreading error:

```
-bash-4.4$ ./configure
Cannot determine OS!
```

Does anyone know what this is? I am probably being COMPLETELY oblivous and there is an easy way to get arround this. But hey, that's for you guys (or girls) to find out.

Thanks!

p.s (I am compiling VirtualBox)

Comment: Looking at the build instructions on the VirtualBox wiki, I don't see anything to suggest that it supports building under Cygwin.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah.  What I was missing is that the tutorial you're following gives extremely bad advice.  Ignore it and start again.  Instructions for building VirtualBox on Windows are available [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Windows%20build%20instructions).